# How do I understand the time evolution of gas temperature in this paper?

Tags: astrophysics, radiative-transfer

I am reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0312524) paper

Title: "Radiative transfer through Galactic medium"

I am having some problems with equation $(8)$:

$$\frac{dT}{dt}=\frac{2(G-L)}{3kn}+\frac Tn\frac{dn_e}{dt}-3\frac{\dot a}a\left(\frac23T+\frac{n_e}nT\right)$$

1. How can I physically understand the second term and the third term?
2. Or, where can I find the answer to my question in terms of "reading a research paper"

I tried

1. integrate (LHS = only the second term)
2. integrate (LHS= only the third term)

but the result doesn't make me feel familiar with any of the equations I know of.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The second term is equivalent to the expansion of a system containing an ideal gas as gas particles enter or leave the system. Using $n$ as number density (in their terms), you will obtain this

$$ T = \frac{p}{nR} $$

$$ \frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{p}{R} \frac{1}{n^2} \frac{dn}{dt} $$

$$ \frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{T}{n} \frac{dn}{dt} $$

The third term is a model of adiabatic expansion. Its derivation is likely in one of the papers included in the references. See in particular the conclusions that reference the paper by Abel et all (1999).